# Keep Reap / Sow results after breaking out of a loop

Tags: procedural-programming, sow-reap, abort

I am doing a long calculation where I create a list using `Reap` and `Sow`. However, sometimes this calculation gets too wild and I build into the code a test to tell me whether it is better to abort the evaluation. However, when I abort, I lose all the potential results from `Reap` and `Sow`. How can I avoid this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
Reap[
 While[some condition,
  result = some calculation;
  Sow[result, list];
  If[some test fails, Abort[]];
 ], {list}
]
```

If I decide to abort the evaluation at some step of the calculation, how can I keep all previous results?

A solution would be to use `Append` instead of `Reap` and `Sow`, but that's too slow. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the right command to use in this context is `Break` rather than `Abort`.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment.